# Jenkins doesn't start a build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, github-webhook, git-webhooks

I have a github webhook that sends request to jenkins BUT jenkins doesn't start my job. In jenkins logs I have found:
Received PushEvent for https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxx from xxxxxxx ⇒ http://xx:xx/github-webhook/

And in my job setting I set project url to https://github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx/

As you can see the difference only in the last slash, but when I remove this slash from jenkins setting, it gets set again

I think the problem is in this last slash.

I have already successfully started my job a few times and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: what is plugin did you install for webhook on jenkins ?

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan I didn't install any plugins itself. I have only predownloaded plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins doesnot have any `webhook` plugins in its self.

You should install this plugin and configuration.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/

Comment: Unfortunately the request still reaches but the build does not start

Comment: I just configured this plugin and it works! Thanks!

Comment: if my answer is helpful, can you tick it as the correct answer ?